# How to make a translucent <input/> and transparent <button/>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following, a translucent input textfield and a transparent button:

[image]

So for `<input/>` tried but can't seem to get it exactly the same. Any guidance or insight on what to improve to make it exactly the same? (such as text cursor color and placeholder size etc.). Also help on the `<button/>` would be greatly appreciated too.

```
   #input-field {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: copy the CSS from where you found the orginal?

Comment: @epascarello It isn't on web but on mobile app so can't

Comment: @YashJain sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: to get it **exactly the same**, you need to keep adjusting your css. It's tedious work and I don't think you can ask people to do it for you

Comment: @JacobGoh I've already done enough but still cant get it so asking for any guidance or insight.

Comment: @JacobGoh Could you show as answer so I can accept and upvote ? Still no luck on my end.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

you just have to set `background-color` to `rgba(255,255,255,0.4)` .. you will have to play with the `%` though.. i..e change `0.4`, `0.3`, etc and for button you can set `background` to `transparent`

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing : border-box; }

body {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}


.container {
  padding: 50px;

  background: rgb(121,68,160);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(121,68,160,1) 0%, rgba(86,93,181,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(121,68,160,1) 0%,rgba(86,93,181,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(121,68,160,1) 0%,rgba(86,93,181,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7944a0', endColorstr='#565db5',GradientType=1 );

}

h1 { margin-bottom: 15px; color: #EEE; }
.input { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.input:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

input, button {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.45);
  font-weight: bold;
}





::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #DDD;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
   color: #DDD;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>User Login</h1>

<form action="#">

 <div class="input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
 </div>
 <div class="input">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
 </div>

 <div class="input" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <button>Login</button>
 </div>

</form>
</div>
```